# ASP.NET MVC 5 Join on Between, no primary key

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, join

I have some interesting code to look at.

I have three tables:

## Table A has 4 columns:

TablePK

UserID

TableBFKID

Score

## Table B has 3 columns:

TablePK

Name

ShortName

## Table c has 4 columns:

TablePK

ScoreMin

ScoreMax

Modifier

So when the full join happens it looks like this:

```
SELECT  B.ShortName 
      , A.Score
      , C.Modifier
FROM TableA A 
     INNER JOIN TableB B ON a.TablePK= B.TablePK 
     INNER JOIN TableC C ON A.Score BETWEEN C.ScoreMin AND C.ScoreMax
```

The results would look like this:

ShortName, Score, Modifier. EX:

CHA, 19, 4

Now I know how to do an Entity Framework join if there is an actual PK or FK, or even if there is only a 0:1 relationship.

But how do you do the join when there is neither a PK nor an FK?

Answer (score 1):

LINQ, including LINQ to Entities, only supports equi-joins.

But you can run SQL directly:

```
var res = myContext.Database.SqlQuery<TResult>("SQL goes here", parmeters...);
```

and EF will map the columns of the result set to the properties of `TResult` (which needs to other connection to the context: it does not need to be an entity type with a `DbSet` typed property in the context).

Comment: Would you do this in the entity model? Or the controller and pass that to a custom view model?

Comment: I've done it in both depending on the wider context. Certainly – ideally – it goes into the lower layers of a properly layered architecture... but lots of applications I not ideally structured.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I wouldn't try to join them, just use a sub-select in your linq to select from the un-joined table where the scores are between your wanted ranges.

```
var results = context.TableA
    .Select(a => new  {
        score = a.Score, //add all needed columns
        tableCs = context.TableC.Where(c => a.Score >= c.ScoreMin && a.Score <= c.ScoreMax)
    });
```

Comment: Where would you add this? in the main Entity model or in the controller and pass it to a new view model?

Comment: Typically this would be in a repository then you would use that to return the results as a view model in the controller.